# How to fix AttributeError:partially initialized module (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: python, exception

I'm running the following Python code in Visual Studio:

---

### app.py   |

```
from Student import Student

student1 = Student("Jim", "Business", 3.1, False)

print(student1.gpa)
```

---

### Student.py   |

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, major, gps, is_on_probation):
        self.name = name
        self.major = major
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.is_on_probation = is_on_probation
```

---

When I try to run it, VS throws the error:

```
cannot import name 'Student' from partially initialized module 'Student' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\cdegr\source\repos\Student\Student.py)
```

There was a similar question that I saw, but there wasn't any fix posted for the original question. Only requests to see the code posted, so here's mine. Why is my code not working?

Comment: Is this the whole code, or is there more?

Answer (score 0):

Your class name and your python file name are the same (Student). This causes the error, and the suspicion of circular imports. Rename the class or the python file name, and app.py should work.

Sidenote: in the `__init__` function, your `gpa` parameter is spelled as `gps`, so you should fix that.